# How get line from web site with Python

Tags: python, string

I want to print only line containing --> REQUIRES="berusky-data"

I try this but not work :

```
import urllib2
import re

f = urllib2.urlopen('http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.1/games/berusk/berusky.info')
r = f.read()


for line in r:
    if "REQUIRES" in r:
          print line,
```

Comment: Are you sure the link is correct? Getting 404.

Comment: Yep, you mistyped `berusky` as `berusk` in the latter part of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) for splitting the data by new-lines and check if `REQUIRES` string  is in `line`:

```
for line in r.splitlines():
    if "REQUIRES" in line:
          print line,
```

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.1/games/berusky/berusky.info')
>>> r = f.read()
>>> for line in r.splitlines():
...     if "REQUIRES" in line:
...         print line,
... 
REQUIRES="berusky-data"
```